# Trouble loading package "prediction" in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I am experiencing some issues loading the `margins` package. I've installed the package like this:

```
install.packages("margins", dependencies = TRUE)
```

The installation goes well, but when I try to load the package, I get this message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘margins’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘prediction’

When I try to install the `prediction` package, R doesn't seem to understand that `prediction` is an actual package. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

When I try to install the `prediction` package, like this,

```
install.packages("prediction", dependencies = TRUE)
```

I don't get anything. This is what my console looks like

>
install.packages("prediction", dependencies = TRUE)

>

I'm not sure why `prediction` won't install on my R Studio, but would appreciate any help! -- Thank you!

Comment: Show the code you used that produced the error message. What happens with `install.packages("prediction")?

Comment: Here's the code: ```> install.packages("prediction")
> library("prediction")
Error in library("prediction") : there is no package called ‘prediction’
> ```

Comment: When you ran `install.packages("prediction") ` did you get an error message?

Comment: Nope, no error message, it just ran for a second, and then it went to an empty ">" symbol

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out I just needed to update my R Studio to the latest version, as well as gofortran and clang. Package was then downloadable!